# Get earliest year from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a couple tables where there is a same field `added`. What I want to do is get the earliest year from all these records.

Tables:

```
comics | movies | tv | tv_episodes
```

Code So Far (Doesn't Work):

```
function getStartYear() {
    include("config.php");
        $query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(added, '%Y') as `added` FROM (comics,movies,tv,tv_episodes) ORDER BY `added` DESC LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            return $row['added'];
        }
}
```

Error Returned:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in E:\xampp\htdocs\mydb\functions\common.php on line 94
```

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

**UPDATE**

So going by Andrew's answer the new query looks like:

```
function getStartYear() {
    include("config.php");
        $query = "SELECT MIN(y) FROM (
SELECT MIN(YEAR(added)) AS y FROM comics 
UNION SELECT MIN(YEAR(added)) AS y FROM movies 
UNION SELECT MIN(YEAR(added)) AS y FROM tv 
UNION SELECT MIN(YEAR(added)) AS y FROM tv_episodes
) AS t1";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            $finalanswer = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            return $finalanswer['t1']; // <-- Line 96
        }else{
            echo mysql_error();
        }
}
```

New Message:

```
Notice: Undefined index: t1 in E:\xampp\htdocs\mydb\functions\common.php on line 96
```

Comment: This error means, that your SQL-query failed. You should start your debugging there.

Comment: Tables listed in a `FROM` clause shouldn't be enclosed in `()`. Then, you have no join conditions between all those listed tables, which will result in a giant cartesian product of all the rows from all tables multiplied by all rows from all tables.  Find out the query syntax error with `mysql_error()`.

Comment: I switched the query up its now layed out like Andrew had suggested. And now it says there is no index for `t1`

Comment: t1 is the table name, you want to get y. So change:

    return $finalanswer['t1']; to $finalanswer['y'];

Also in the query, change SELECT MIN(y) to SELECT MIN(y) AS y so it sets up the alias, or just return the first column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could retrieve it through SQL using a UNION sub-query:

```
SELECT MIN(y) FROM (
    SELECT MIN(YEAR(added)) AS y FROM table1
    UNION SELECT MIN(YEAR(added)) AS y FROM table2
    ...
) AS t1;
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: t1 in E:\xampp\htdocs\mydb\functions\common.php on line 96

Answer (score 1):

First you should be checking to make sure your SQL statement actually returns the desired data.  Run the script itself in some sort of SQL viewer (or phpMySQL), or

```
echo mysql_error();
```

just to be sure you don't have an invalid SQL statement.

The invalid resource error you're getting indicates to me that the "$result" of your mysql_query function is not a valid resource.

So:

```
if (!$result = mysql_query($query))
    echo mysql_error();
```

if you do have an error in your query, diagnose and fix and go from there...

As it stands right now, you're doing a "return" from the middle of a loop, which means you're returning the first object found in the result set.

I would consider instead of "looping", do this:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    $finalanswer = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    return $finalanswer['added'];
}
else
    echo mysql_error();
```

error trapping is kind of a nice thing to get in the habit of. :)

Comment: This still returns the same message.

Comment: If that's the case, you're doing it wrong.  The mysql_error() will look fundamentally different from the PHP error you're getting.  You're not looking in the right place.  $result is not a valid "resource", meaning your mysql_query did not return appropriate database results, meaning your SQL query is flawed in some way.

Comment: changed my query to Andrew's suggestion and it solved that problem but i got a new one. undefined index on t1... check my comment above :d ty.

Comment: @rackemup420 Also, be sure to error trap on the attempt to QUERY the database, not just on the attempt to fetch a row from the result set.  Do it in BOTH places.

Comment: I wrote it out like you put in your example.

Comment: @rackemup420 since your query only returns one field, you could just do a number-based index...such as $finalanswer[0]... mysql_fetch_array will allow both numerical index and name-based index lookups... (see the documentation for it http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php - the default for the result type is MYSQL_BOTH).